# Adding fields to ModelForm programatically not showing in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have a usecase where I want to add fields to a modelform in django admin, but when trying to add them in the __init__function like this:

```
class PackageFileInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = File
      fields = '__all__'

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['test'] = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Nothing shows up in the form. However if I do the form like this:

```
class PackageFileInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    test = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'
```

Why does the **init** version not work?

Comment: What does the `File` model look like? Does it have the `test` field? If so, it would be redundant with `__all__`, but if it doesn't it probably shouldn't show, since it's not in the original model.

Comment: @IvanBalepin It does not have a test field. That is my goal, to add a field that is not present on the model.